# code first approach error: The specified type member 'xxxxx' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, code-first

In an effort to further abstract my repository layer I have attempted to follow the code-first approach as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236639.aspx.

I have a many-to-many relationship between Account and Subscription entities. A Navigation property exists on each entity pointing to the other (e.g. Account.Subscriptions).

Before I created my own model I was using the Entity generated model and the below worked fine ("db" is the entity context) :

```
public IQueryable<Account> GetBySubscriptionId(int subId)
{
    return from a in db.Accounts
           where a.Subscriptions.Any(s => s.SubscriptionId == subId)
           select a;
}
```

Now the model for Account looks like this:

```
public class Account
    {
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // nav properties
        public virtual List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

And when I try to run the same LINQ query now I get this error:

> "The specified type member
>   'Subscriptions' is not supported in
>   LINQ to Entities. Only initializers,
>   entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported."

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Code First are you using and do you have any Code First mappings or configuration setup for these two entities?

Comment: not using Code First templates as such, just that style of model declared in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the signature from

```
        // nav properties 
        public virtual List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
```

to

```
        // nav properties 
        public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
```

Shamelessly nicked from Scott Hanselmann's demo here - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx which uses this pattern, also here's a Scott Guthrie demo using the same idea http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx .

`List<T>` is a concrete implementation of various interfaces (ICollection, IQueryable, IEnumerable etc), Entity Framework uses proxy objects when it retrieves things from the database, hence the `virtual` declarations, which use different implementations of these interfaces which is where your error is coming from.